# Finding it difficult getting to grips with LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, strategy

So I have spent about a week now learning libGDX and have made very little progress.

I started small and wanted to make a strategy game where there is a tiled map of squares and you control a ship, move it from tile to tile to take out enemy ships. After a week of troubleshooting I have only just managed to import and render the map and can barely get sprites to render in the right places. Having read the libGDX wiki multiple times I can still find very little documentation online about making strategy games with libGDX and I'm pretty stuck.

Did I pick the wrong framework ? or am I just not looking in the right places?

From what I have read online libGDX is not the best on documentation so is it right for a beginner like me or would something else be better? Thanks :)

Comment: I've had a similar experience, and there is definitely a learning period. I'd recommend identifying a single problem at a time, and use the wiki, stack overflow, and libGDX chat to solve it. There is a learning curve, but it's not too steep.

Comment: The framework is there mainly as a base for expansion. You can use the existing APIs such as Scene2D, or you can create your own from scratch to suit your standards. Personally, I never have and never will use Scene2D, because I prefer a more component-based architecture, so I stick to using Ashley. I also have previous experience with XNA, so I like to make my coding environment feel like it did when I used XNA. You just need to remember that while the tools are there for you to use, you aren't bound to use them. Go with what makes you comfortable!

Answer (score 0):

Try some video tutorials online.

LWJGL is several times more difficult to use than LibGDX and I got relatively good at it through ThinMatrix's video tutorials.

Hearing somebody explain *why* something is part of the library, as well as how to use it, with the example, is extremely helpful.

The following goes without saying but: don't copy or fully understand everything that you are copying.

The fact that it's a strategy game is pretty irrelevant - the LibGDX framework works for any sort of game you want.